# Do I need .BeginEdit() and .EndEdit() if I'm creating an in-memory DataTable?

Tags: c#, datatable, datatables

I'm creating a DataTable based on reflected properties, so nothing during its creation is tied to a database. I don't see the need for using BeginEdit and EndEdit in this context, though I can't find an example that doesn't tie a DataTable to SQL.

In this case, do I need these methods when adding rows?

Answer (score 0):

No you don't - unless you want the datatable to contribute referential integrity or other validation capabilities.
These methods are used to generate differential insert, update and delete statements in connection with dataadapters, and enforce relations and validations.

in-memory editing, adding, and removing rows works reliable without these methods. You can even add and remove columns dynamically.